# New field added whenever I export shapefile to the geodatabase

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes, delete

[image]I don't know why this is keep happening, but I created shapefile in QGIS and opened the shapefile from ArcGIS. I needed to create geodatabase to put in all of my shapefile, but whenever I do that, point shapefiles are fine, but my line shapefiles automatically create new field.

The main problem is that I cannot delete that new field in my attribute table, but I want them to be disappeared.

It is just one field that is keep showing up. I got the shape_leng for the shapefile's length(m) but when I export that into geodatabase, the new field shape_length comes up. It doesn't let me delete this field and values are very different.

Is there any ways to fix this or delete this field permanently?

Comment: The field is automatically calculated for geodatabases, and will depend on the CRS of the file. What projection/units is the geodatabase in?

Comment: It's in NAD83_BC_Albers

Comment: And is that the same as what the shapefile was in when you calculated the `shape_leng` field? If not, set the geodatabase to the same projection as the shapefile, and see if the values match up. If the projections are the same, could you edit your question to include a screenshot so that we can see how different the fields are?

Comment: Some of the values have significant difference, so I can't disregard these values. I have the screenshot attached. My original value is shape_leng; and I can't delete, edit the shape_length column.

Comment: Seconding @JoshC's question: What was the CRS of the shapefile when you calculated `shape_leng`?

Comment: @smiller it was also NAD83_BC_Albers in QGIS

Comment: As already commented you cant delete some fields but you can hide them by right-clicking the layer - properties - fields - uncheck the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

File geodatabases have a certain number of fields that are managed internally and **you cannot modify or delete them**. Shape_Length is one of them.

The most probable cause for divergent values between what you calculated in QGIS and what ArcGIS calculates is that you haven't set your feature dataset/class properly.

If you import many shapefiles from different sources, the file structure in your geodatabase should almost always have your feature classes imported inside a feature dataset as the CRS is then managed at that level. When you import your shapefile in the feature dataset, as long as you have set the CRS properly, the data should be projected properly and the Shape_Length field should be calculated with correct values.

But more importantly, make sure you are using the correct CRS. There is both a NAD83 (WKID 3005) and NAD83 CSRS (WKID 3153) version of BC Environment Albers which could be where the divergences are occuring since they are different datums.